# regular expression with negative match

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to construct a regular expression with multiple condition with negative match.

regular expression (1)
--> line contains value1 and does not contain value2

regular expression (2)
--> line does not contain value3 or contains value4

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sample input and output will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

*Generally* speaking this could be achieved with lookaheads.
Your **first** expression is translated to regex like so:

```
(?=.*(?:value1))(?!.*(?:value2)).*
# looks ahead twice
# once for value1 (positive)
# and again for value2 (negative)
# the dot-star actually matches the whole line
```

Here's an [online demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vJ6oG0/1). But it could be different depending on your actual situation. The second is left as an exercise :-)